# Text inside some buttons in my android application is not shown as i want it to be.Any suggestion?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Here is my xml code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSinInverse"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="fill"   
    android:text="      -1sin"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This does not produce satisfactory results. Below is a screen shot of present output:

[image]

I tried to put image of sin inverse above button but then just image appeared not the button below it.When i do it this way can't be sure if the text would even appear on correclty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android supports [Styled String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) and the `<sup>` tag is supported as well. So just add

```
<string name="sin_inv">sin<sup>-1</sup></string>
```

to one of your resource files and apply the string to the Button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSinInverse"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="fill"   
    android:text="@string/sin_inv"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: i added above string resource in res/values/strings
but the buuton showed sin&lt;sup&gt;-1&lt;/sup&gt; not sin inverse as intended

Comment: My fault, sorry. It should not have been XML encoded.